# How to implement a list feature that limits options based on other selected options?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

This is a general design question to a problem I am facing.

I am implementing a UI list of items where the user can select multiple items at once. Some of the options, however, are grouped in a sense that only one of those items may be selected at once due to business logic. E.g. If list contains items, A, B, C there needs to be a way to specify the logic where either A, B or C can be selected at once.

I have considered implementing within the class design a variable which contains list of the other items which are grouped and so cannot be selected if any in that list are already selected. However, this seems like a difficult thing to maintain because if there are 3 items in a group, all 3 must be updated if an additional item is added to that group.

What would be a better design solution to this problem?

Comment: why not just set a variable to hold an enum type such as `int selected = A/B/C/Unchecked`? Then each element will check it before update. As my experiences of UI programming, it's better to hooks on all components in a 'update' callback, rather then notify others in a frame, such as "onDraw" on Android or "Update" in Unity.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to have an `std::shared_ptr<unsigned> group_selection` as a member in each selectable object. Then if two objects, say `a` and `c` must not be selected at the same time have the shared pointer point to the same object. That way, selecting `a` and updating `++*a.group_selection` will enable you to check if `*c.group_selection` is zero before selecting `c`.

Example:

```
#include <memory>

class Selectable {
  private:
    bool selected = false;
    std::shared_ptr<unsigned> group_selection;
  public:
    Selectable() : group_selection(std::make_shared<unsigned>(0)) {}
    ~Selectable() {
      unselect();
    }
    void add_to_group(Selectable const& of) {
      group_selection = of.group_selection;
    }
    bool can_select() const {
      return *group_selection == 0;
    }
    void select() {
      if (!selected)
        ++*group_selection;
      selected = true;
    }
    void unselect() {
      if (selected)
        --*group_selection;
      selected = false;
    }
};
```